# is there a way to reference all items except $(this) - Jquery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

if I have multiple items, set as `class="item"`, is it possible to do something like:

```
$(".item").mouseover(function(){
        $(!this).hide() // every .item but $(this)
         });
```

Comment: `.not` is the word you are looking for :)

Comment: Actually `.not()` since you cannot use `this` inside a selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's easily possible:

```
$('.item').not(this).hide();
```

You can optimize this a bit by storing the items list:

```
var items = $('.item');
items.mouseover(function() {
    items.not(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var items = $(".item"); // caching .item's
items.mouseover(function(){
   items.not(this).hide() // every .item but $(this)                     
});
```